# How to select directories with wildcards

Tags: unix

I have a unix script I wish to run on multiple files. logging structure is such that:

```
/loghome_dir/Env_AppName_AppInstance/app-server.date.log
```

I wish to run the script as flows:

cd into the correct directory and check todays log file, however I'm having trouble doing this in my script.

Ideally I want something along the lines of:

```
cd /loghome_dir/*AppInstance/
```

However this is the wrong use of the wild card I need something to simply search the directory for my matching AppInstance.

Comment: Why is `/loghome_dir/*AppInstance/` wrong? How would a matching AppInstance look like?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could look like

```
#! /bin/sh

today=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
myscript.sh /loghome_dir/Env_*_AppInstance/app-server.${today}.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you can list the directory and then check them out one by one.

```
preDIR=$PWD
for dir in `ls /loghome_dir/*AppInstnace/`   
do 
cd $dir  
$(YOUR WORK)  
cd $preDIR  
done
```

Or just use `find` for finding the file using its time options.

> find {path} -ctime 1 -type f

To find the file which created or modified 24hrs ago.